# How do I load an Order by Id and include all attributes?

Tags: attributes, orders, filter

I have a simple case where I need to load an order by an ID and include all it's attributes.

So far I can load the order by id, but can't find out how to include all attributes:

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(123);
```

Or I can load the collection with all attributes, but can't figure out how to filter by id:

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributesToSelect(*);
```

Comment: addIdFilter() looked promising, but doesn't work (looks like it's within the ORM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to do it via a collection, I guess the syntax would be:

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(*)->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', 123)->getFirstItem();
```

However what fields are you looking for that aren't present in the model resulting from:

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(123);
```

In newer version of Magento (1.4+ I think, maybe earlier) the order table is a flat table not EAV. I'm reasonably sure the fields should all be present without any extra work.

Comment: ahh, you're right.  I was expecting many more fields on the result--but it looks like I just need to drill down on it.